# Reactjs Redux updating data values from the state/store with an input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a state that has multiple users  initial State of the reducer

```js
const initialState = [
  {
    id: 1,
   name:"thename",
   lastName: "Lastname"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
   name:"thename",
   lastName: "Lastname"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
   name:"thename",
   lastName: "Lastname"
  },
];
```

And a component that shows them in a table, and the table has the functionality to update this values.
So the thing i want to do is to take this values, make a copy of them to the state of the component and update them with my inputs.

Copying:

```
const users= useSelector((state) => state.usersReducer);
const [userState, setUserState] = useState(users)
  useEffect(() => {
    setUserState(users); // if the users state from the redux grows
  }, [applicants]);
```

Mapping to display the data:

```js
{ usersState.map( user=>{
<input onChange={(e) => handleChange(user)} value={user.name} >
})}
```

and with this handleChange

```js
const handleChange = (data) => {
    setUserState((user) => {
      return [...user.filter((x) => x.id !== data.id), data];
    });
  };
```

but when I type in the input nothing happen...
Because I could have multiple users, i'm mapping through them, I did forms before while learning, and never had this problem where the input doesn't change at all. But never had to do something like this, so i'm in trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have noticed two issues here in your snippet.

- This component shouldn't have users as component state.

> The selector is approximately equivalent to the mapStateToProps
> argument to connect conceptually. The selector will be called with the
> entire Redux store state as its only argument. The selector will be
> run whenever the function component renders (unless its reference
> hasn't changed since a previous render of the component so that a
> cached result can be returned by the hook without re-running the
> selector). useSelector() will also subscribe to the Redux store, and
> run your selector whenever an action is dispatched.

- `dispatch` should be call in `handleChange` method to update redux state and re-render component

For example:

```js
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const handleChange = (e, user) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'UPDATE_USER',
      data: {
        ...user,
        name: e.target.value
      },
    })
```

Comment: This was actually what I ended up doing. After reading @Piyush Rana answer and yours I finally figured out what was the problem. 
This is the solution to the problem, I was watching the problem in a different way which was wrong. Thank you for the reply, this helps me a lot, and reduced my code a lot too.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna update redux state also, you need to call `dispatch` to update redux state through reducer in `handleChange` function.

Comment: ohh I see, the problem was that I was assigning the state based on the reduxstate that wans't getting update at the same time. Thanks ! this fixed my problem